# Segmentation fault: 11 when using scanf. Won't read past UUN?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am a c beginner and have searched all questions and tried the relevant answers but nothing seems to work. 
It reads name and surname and UUN and then says segmentation fault: 11 and exits.
Please help!

```
typedef struct {
char *name;
char *surname;
char *UUN;
char *department;
char gender;
int age;
} student_t;


int main(void)  {
int i, len;
student_t student_t[6];

student_t[0].name = "John";
student_t[0].surname = "Bishop";
student_t[0].UUN = "s1234";
student_t[0].department = "Inf";
student_t[0].gender = 'm';
student_t[0].age = 18;

student_t[1].name = "Lady";
student_t[1].surname = "Cook";
student_t[1].UUN = "s2345";
student_t[1].department = "Eng";
student_t[1].gender = 'f';
student_t[1].age = 21;

student_t[2].name = "James";
student_t[2].surname = "Jackson";
student_t[2].UUN = "s3456";
student_t[2].department = "Eng";
student_t[2].gender = 'm';
student_t[2].age = 17;

for (i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf(" %s", student_t[i].name);
    printf("Enter your surname: ");
    scanf(" %s", student_t[i].surname);
    printf("Enter your UUN: ");
    scanf(" %s", student_t[i].UUN);
    printf("Enter your department: ");
    scanf(" %s", student_t[i].department);
    printf("Enter your gender: ");
    scanf(" %c", &student_t[i].gender);
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf(" %d", &student_t[i].age);
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You never allocated memory for the strings, so you're writing through uninitialized pointers.

Comment: ..and the: 'for (i = 4; i <= 6; i++)', together with all the [1], [2], [3] dmonstrates that the OP does not know that array indices start at 0, so with 'student_t student_t[6];', indices 0,1,2,3,4,5 are all valid.  6 is not.

Comment: Even if the first block runs OK because of loading pointers to string literals, it's a very bad idea to treat the first three as any diffferent to the last three.  OP should malloc the space and strcpy in the data for both blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is in the loop where you do a read into an uninitialized pointer, for example:

> scanf(" %s", student_t[i].name);

A possible fix might go along these lines:

```
char tmp[256];
if (scanf(" %255s", tmp) != 1) { /* handle error */ }
student_t[i].name = strdup(tmp);
```

One additional common source of a segfault event, (which you do avoid), is this kind of line:

```
student_t[1].name = "Lady";
```

which is setting the field 'name' to point to a literal string ("Lady" here) which is very likely located in read-only memory.  Then if you were to later attemp to read into that same location:

```
scanf(" %s", student_t[i].name);
```

it would be trying to write the data scanned into where that pointer is pointing (into read-only memory). This is undefined behavior and would also lead to a segfault event.  Even if the original value ("Lady") happened to be located in read-write memory, it may only be just large enough for "Lady" -- there is no guarantee that it can hold any longer string (say, "Christopher").

As with your other uses of scanf, the line does have a couple of other problems:

1. you should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  (in this case if the returned value not equal to 1, then it failed)
2. the format specifier: '%s' does not limit the number of characters input.  This can result in a input buffer overflow, which is undefined behavior, leading to a segfault event.

Suggest using:

```
char buffer[256];
...
printf("Enter your name: ");
if ( 1 != scanf( " %255s", buffer ) )
{
     perror( " scanf for name failed" );
     cleanup();  // free all memory allocations
     exit(1);
}
// implied else, scanf successful
student_t[i].name = strdup(buffer);
```

To make the `cleanup()` much easier, suggest changing lines like this:

```
student_t[2].name = "James";
```

to

```
student_t[2].name = strdup("James");
```

because memory allocated with `strdup()` should be returned to the system with `free()` while literal values (like "Lady") can not be.

Comment: `student_t[i].name` does not write the string literal because `i` never takes values for which that pointer had been pointed to a string literal

Comment: @JohnHascall,   this statement: *because memory allocated with strdup() should be returned to the system with free() while literal values (like "Lady") can not be.* is not quite correct.  The reason to use strdup() on the fields is because then 'cleanup()' can just loop; through the array 'student_t[]' without any special knowledge about where the string literals (in read only memory) ends and the pointers to data in the 'heap' begins

Comment: regarding the edit about writing to read only memory:  trying to write into read only memory will always result in a immediate seg fault event.  so any considerations about size of the data are pointless.  'read only memory' means the memory mapped page has the 'read' attribute but not the 'write' attribute.

Comment: @user3629249, explaining the WHY of the difficulty with the cleanup loop was what I trying to get at.

Comment: @user3629249, many compilers have an option to put string literals in read-write memory (and on some, generally older, systems they are always in read-write memory).  On these systems, even though it is a terrible idea, you can overwrite string literals, but if you exceed the length of the original string literal, you are extremely likely to be scribbling over other data